# how to match an expression that starts and ends with a cariage return and belongs to a group?

Tags: c#, regex

Sample string

```
+ABC:108\r\nmessage a\r\n+ABC:117\r\nmessage b\r\n
```

here is my initial regex

`+ABC:(\d+)\r\n(.+)\r\n`

```
Groups
Group 1: Index
Group 2: Message
```

Comment: use `.+?` - it is lazy match and find the first **minimal** entrence of part of regex. also `\w` - is an any symbol, using in names of vars.  and another: `\s` - is an any space symbol (tab, space, end of line)

Answer (score 0):

Where is your exact problem?

I see this points:

1. If you want to match the `+` literally you have to escape it in your regex `\+ABC:(\d+)\r\n(.+)\r\n`. Only one `\` if you use verbatim string (`@"regex"`) to define your regex
2. If you don't use the `[Singleline][1]` option it should be no greediness problem since the `.` will not match newline characters.
3. Are you sure that `\r\n` is your newline? Maybe use `\r?\n` to be more flexible.

Comment: does C# supports `\s`- "whitespace"(tab, space, endl) symbol?

Comment: so, my solution in perl-way is : 
`while($str =~ m/((\d+)\s+(.+))+/g ){print "index: $1\n message: $2\n";}`  `g` is global searching (for all).